# Joomla News feed component

Tags: joomla, rss, feed

Im trying to display an rss feed from external site.

ive managed to create a news feed under Components -> News feeds -> Feed.

how do i get this to display on my internal pages?

or is there a better way to do this?

my template file looks like this

```
<div id="main-content">

    <jdoc:include type="message" />

    <div id="left-menu">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />
    </div>

    <div id="home-content">
        <div id="body-content">
        </div>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" style="xhtml" />
    </div>  

    <div id="rss-feed">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="rss" style="xhtml" />
    </div>


       <div id="right-content">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml" />
       </div>           
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

install this:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/rss-readers/1649?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czozOiJyc3MiO2k6MTtzOjQ6InJzcyciO30%3D

put in to the rss position, in the module parameters put in the rss url and done.